# CMake errors with building russimp

Tags: rust, cmake

I'have include the next line into my Cargo.toml:

```
russimp =  { version = "3.1.1", features = ["static-link"] }
```

And with **cargo build** I catch the error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/***/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/russimp-sys-2.0.1/assimp" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

I'm building on Windows11 and MSVS-2022 as a compiler.
**Do you have any suggestions how to fix the russimp build?**

P.S. As far as I understand the actual error is caused by russimp-sys assimp build-script:

```
  process didn't exit successfully: "C:\Users\...\target\debug\build\russimp-sys-1b09328991ac181d\build-script-build" (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\...\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\russimp-sys-2.0.1\\assimp" "-G" "Visual Studio 17 2022" "-Thost=x64" "-Ax64" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF" "-DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF" "-DASSIMP_BUILD_ZLIB=ON" "-DLIBRARY_SUFFIX=" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\...\\target\\debug\\build\\russimp-sys-fed8cf10a5d44e04\\out\\static" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= /EHsc -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= /EHsc -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= /EHsc -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= /EHsc -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_RELEASE= -nologo -MT -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
```

I've tried to clone assimp into the `/.cargo/registry/.../russimp-sys-2.0.1/assimp` directory and have caught the error with some CMake variables:

```
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: "C:\Users\...\target\debug\build\russimp-sys-bd858afe6b188859\build-script-build" (exit code: 101)
  --- stderr
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS
      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_RELEASE
```

P.P.S As Tsyvarev mentioned the given above stderr output was not an error. Looking closer I've found that main thread is panicked with: `Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: ['clang.dll', 'libclang.dll'], set the LIBCLANG_PATH`. After the paht update the russimp-sys crate (unsafe rust binding with assimp, version 2.0.1) has been build successfully!
Still, the russimp crate failed:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\russimp-1.0.6\src\mesh.rs:52:21
   |
52 |             method: mesh.mMethod,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u32, found i32
```

Comment: "Get the error with some CMake variables:" - The output you show contains only the **warning**, which doesn't prevent the project to be configured and built. The error message is somewhere else.